# Vue Unit test Input value not set

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing

I am using Vue with typescript and attempting a unit test of the input value for a login page.
The test sets the input value, then checks that the value equals what was entered, except the value checked is coming back empty "" and I cannot figure out why.

Homepage.vue:

```
<form class="form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <input
          id="userNameTextInput"
          v-model="username"
          placeholder="Name"
          minlength="2"
        /><br />
        <input
          id="passwordTextInput"
          type="password"
          v-model="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          minlength="8"
        /><br />
        <button
          id="submitButton"
          color="white"
          background="darkslateblue"
          type="submit"
          @click="submit"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <div id="incorrectLoginBlock" v-show="toggleIncorrectLogin">
          <p>Incorrect Membername or Password</p>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Homepage.spec.ts:

```
import HomePage from '@/components/HomePage.vue';
import {mount, VueWrapper} from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('HomePage.vue', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(HomePage);
  });

  it('Incorrect login pops up', async () => {
        const userTextInputIncorrect = wrapper.find('#userNameTextInput');
        userTextInputIncorrect.setValue('wrongPass');
        expect(userTextInputIncorrect.element.textContent).toContain(
        'incorrectName',
    );
```

The Error:

expect(received).toContain(expected) //  indexOf

Expected substring: "incorrectName"

Received string:    ""

const userTextInputIncorrect = wrapper.find('#userNameTextInput');

userTextInputIncorrect.setValue('wrongPass');

expect(userTextInputincorrect.element.textContent).toBe('incorrectName');

Comment: You probably need to await `userTextInputIncorrect.setValue('wrongPass');`. https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#setting-element-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work:

```
it("Incorrect login pops up", async () => {
  const userTextInputIncorrect = wrapper.find("#userNameTextInput");
  await userTextInputIncorrect.setValue("wrongPass");

  expect(
    (userTextInputIncorrect.element as HTMLInputElement).value
  ).toContain("incorrectName");
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU FLORENT!

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = wrapper.find('input');
const element = input.element as HTMLInputElement;

let value = 'Test value';
await input.setValue(value);
expect(element.value).toEqual(value);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**